# Why does this code generate a "Potential resource leak" warning?

Tags: java, eclipse, warnings, static-analysis, resource-leak

Eclipse (Juno) gives the following warning:

> Potential resource leak: 'os' may not be closed

at the first line of the `try` body in this code:

```
static void saveDetails(byte[] detailsData) {
    OutputStream os = null;
    try {
        os = sContext.openFileOutput(DETAILS_FILE_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        os.write(detailsData);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.w(LOG_TAG, "Unable to save details", e);
    } finally {
        if (os != null) {
            try {
                os.close();
            } catch (IOException ignored) {
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The method `openFileOutput` is declared to throw a `FileNotFoundException`.

Is this a false positive? It seems like a fairly vanilla execution path analysis.

Comment: It would be easier if you indicated which line eclipse is complaining about, but I'd guess that it's related to the openFileOuput line - How long does the opened object live?  Does the file need to be closed?

Comment: @atk -- The OP indicates that the warning is on the first line of the try body. So `os = sContext.OpenFileOutput...`.

Comment: If `sContext` is null, then a NullPointerException will be thrown and the finally will never trigger since it's not a caught Exception. In this case, `os` will not be closed (or opened).

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas, A) `finally` *will* be triggered, B) if `sContext` was null, then there wouldn't be any `os` to close anyway.

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas: oops - guess I missed that!

Comment: You can't blame a static analysis tool for getting confused on that code. It confuses me. Much better to split the two uses of `try` (`catch` and `finally`), avoiding the use of `null`s.

Comment: @TomHawtin-tackline - What's confusing about the code? It's pretty standard stuff--basically what Brian Goetz recommends in his article [Good Housekeeping Practices](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-jtp03216/index.html). Also, what do you mean by splitting the `try/catch`?

Comment: @TedHopp Empirically, when people use this approach they mess it up. Even when told how they messed up, the correction are also often messed up. You can also tell by looking at the code. By "split the two uses of `try`", I mean replace `... try { ... ... } catch (...) { ... } finally { ... }` with `try { ... try { ... } finally { ... } catch { ... }`. (And then remove all that `if` and `null` stuff.)

Comment: Please open a bug against JDT/Core - https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/enter_bug.cgi?product=JDT

Comment: @DeepakAzad - Done. It's bug #386534.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In my opinion, this is a false positive. Your resource is closed in a "finally" block, so I cannot see what could go wrong here.

As a sidenote, if you are using Java 7, I'd recommend using the "try-with-resources" idiom.

```
static void saveDetails(byte[] detailsData) {    
    try (OutputStream os = sContext.openFileOutput(DETAILS_FILE_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);) {
        os = sContext.openFileOutput(DETAILS_FILE_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        os.write(detailsData);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.w(LOG_TAG, "Unable to save details", e);
    }
}
```

Comment: I just tried, and IntelliJ does not trigger any warning on your code. This gets me even more confident about the fact that it is a false positive in Eclipse. And yep, I dare comment on my own answer :)

Comment: Thanks for the IntelliJ test. I like the Java 7 syntax, but unfortunately this is a Java 6 project. :(

Answer (score 0):

What if you move both open and close to first try clause? They throw the same type of exception. And remove the if os != null.

Comment: That won't work--the `try` block might exit prematurely due to an exception thrown by `os.write` and then the `os.close()` call would be skipped.

Answer (score -2):

My guess is it's because you have `if (os != null)` before closing. Since it's conditional it's possible that the OutputStream is not closed.

What happens if you try:

```
static void saveDetails(byte[] detailsData) {
    OutputStream os = null;
    try {
        os = sContext.openFileOutput(DETAILS_FILE_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        os.write(detailsData);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.w(LOG_TAG, "Unable to save details", e);
    } finally {
        try {
            os.close();
        } catch (IOException ignored) {
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Then if `os` *is* null, you'll throw a NullPointerException in your `finally`.

Comment: The question is, will `sContext.openFileOutput` ever return null?

Comment: @SteveKuo Really the question is, will `openFileOutput` ever throw any kind of exception in any circumstance ever.

Comment: @Tom, yes I see, you are correct. If `openFileOutput` throws an exception, then `os` will be null.

Comment: @SteveKuo It can't be undefined - that wont compile. (I see before the edit, you code wouldn't compile.) These things are difficult to follow, so I strongly suggest not doing the `null` dance. And to tempt you to do the right thing, Java SE 7 has the third form of `try` (forget what they're calling it).

Comment: I tried removing the `if (is != null)` from the `finally` clause. It didn't eliminate the "Potential resource leak" warning and it added a "may be null" warning inside the `finally` clause.

Comment: The whole resource leak analysis seems to be completely broken in Juno - it even complains about methods with a throw clause that do 'new Something().doSomething();'. Useless noise warnings, thus the first thing to disable. If I wanted stupid noise warnings I'd use a checking plugin like PMD (with lots more questionable warnings).