# Under which circumstance would this resource be leaking?

Tags: java, eclipse

Eclipse 4 gives a warning which says the `stmt` may potentially not be closed and cause a resource leak:

```
class Test {
    public void test() {
        PreparedStatement stmt = null;
        try {
            stmt = HibernateSession.instance().connection().prepareStatement("");
        } catch (final SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (stmt != null)
                try {
                    stmt.close();
                } catch (final SQLException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
        }
    }
}
```

Under which circumstance would that happen?

Comment: that's not the worst Eclipse bug

Comment: @OlegMikheev that's not a bug, that's a feature.  And I don't mean this sarcastically, it's actually a useful feature.

Comment: I like that feature... it helps me sometimes, but I cannot quite understand why the above code would generate the resource management warning - bug?

Comment: And here's one of many duplicates:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11786637/why-does-this-code-generate-a-potential-resource-leak-warning

Comment: I can't see how `stmt` would not be closed but the connection won't ever be closed.

Comment: my duplicate wasn't quite accurate, you are doing something more subtle (and wrong, see my answer)

Comment: Eclipse is not smarter than you, that's all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess the conclusion here is: this is an Eclipse bug?

Comment: Looks like an Eclipse bug to me. Maybe Eclipse sees that there is a path through the `finally` (when `stmt` is null) that causes `stmt.close()` not to be called.

Answer (score -1):

A leak is possible if an exception is thrown when you call `stmt.close()` in the `finally` block.

Comment: and how do you handle such a leak?

Answer (score -1):

The problem was that in your `finally` block an exception might potentially occur, which would prevent `stmt` from closing.

One workaround is that you can replace everything in the `finally` block with:

```
JDBCUtilities.close(stmt);
```

See the [docs](http://www.athenasource.org/docs/javadoc/org/athenasource/framework/unidbi/JDBCUtilities.html#close%28java.sql.Statement%29) for `JDBCUtilities.close`. As you can see, no exception will be thrown using this utility method so you don't need to worry about resource leak. One additional benefit is that the utility method handles the `null` case for `stmt` as well so we don't need to code it ourselves.

Actually, it is [good practice](http://www2.sys-con.com/itsg/virtualcd/java/archives/0504/ashmore/index.html) to use `JDBCUtilities`.

Comment: It'll confuse Eclipse even more, which cannot possibly know what `JDBCUtilities.close(stmt)` does.

Comment: @irreputable How? Eclipse only checks for syntactic errors, checked exceptions, etc. I don't think it cares about or understands the business logic. In the `finally` block we want to close `stmt` which is exactly what `JDBCUtilities.close` does.

Comment: Eclipse does not know that `JDBCUtilities.close(stmt)` calls `stmt.close()`

Comment: @irreputable I don't think Eclipse needs to know that. Can you give an example where it might complain?

Comment: I mean Eclipse would issue the same warning, since it doesn't know the stmt is closed for sure.

Answer (score -2):

You need to be using Java 7's try with resources or a try-finally block:

```
try(stmt = HibernateSession.instance().connection().prepareStatement("")) {


}
```

This warning will be generated on types that inherit from `AutoCloseable` that are not guaranteed to be closed.  (Or possible `Closeable`, I forget which).

Now that I see what you're asking, just write less complicated code.

```
Foo f = null; // don't do this, but it's what you're doing
f = new Foo();
```

Is what you're doing, and you found one of several situations where you actually have to pay a penalty for this extraneous work.

Furthermore your `try/finally` should be clean.  `.close()` can't throw, why are you catching?

```
try { // don't do this
    stmt.close();
}
catch(SQLException exc) {

}
```

Should generate an Eclipse warning telling you that you're catching something that doesn't throw.  That might even be a compile error, not sure, but sounds like you would benefit from playing with Eclipse > Preferences > Compiler and reviewing what warnings are intelligent.  If you don't understand a warning, google it and see if it would be helpful to you, don't just skip over it. (sort of like you did with this one).

Comment: thanks, that would make the code much clearer. I wish my employer would adapt jdk 1.7.

Comment: [what do you mean _.close() can't throw_ ?](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#close%28%29)

Comment: @OlegMikheev my bad, I implicitly assumed the AutoCloseable class was designed correctly (I've made this mistake in Java before).